# Axios post request not getting proper response in Node Js

Tags: node.js, axios, fetch

Below is the details of API call

URL : https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/query

POST DATA :

```
{
    "query":{},
    "options":{
        "pagination":false,
        "populate":[
            {
                "path":"rocket",
                "select":{
                    "name":1
                }
            },
            {
                "path":"payloads",
                "select":{
                    "customers":1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Using axios getting success response but in response?.data getting below data

[image]

Using fetch it's working fine.

[image]

Do I need to set any config in axios?
Thank you.

Comment: It's an Axios bug ~ https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a bug in a 3rd-party library

Comment: Also voted to close. For a quick fix, downgrade Axios to version 1.1.0 until a patch is released.

Comment: Thank you.
'Accept-Encoding': 'identity' is working for now

Answer (score -1):

Get the desired output using the below code.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
"query": {},
"options": {
"pagination": false,
"populate": [
  {
    "path": "rocket",
    "select": {
      "name": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "path": "payloads",
    "select": {
      "customers": 1
    }
   }
  ]
}
});

var config = {
 method: 'post',
 url: 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/query',
 headers: { 
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data : data
 };

 axios(config)
 .then(function (response) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the compression of the response from the server. You can look into the response header(**[Transfer-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding)**) to know the encoding and use the third-party libraries to decode it.

Alternative is passing **["Accept-Encoding": "identity"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)** header in the axios request headers.